# Samsung 860 EVO for installing Windows and Gaming

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, gaming

Is it good to use a Samsung 860 EVO 1TB to install windows 10 and Steam games? I'm a everyday computer user and I do play games most of the time. installing windows and games Will that have an effect on SSD durability?

Comment: Currently SSD match or exceed the durability of the old HDDs. I suppose you wouldn't be asking the same question about HDDs, would you? There, just use it and don't worry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - SSD's are in the order of 10 times as fast (5 times as fast in raw speed, but hundreds of times faster when accessing lots of small files), and about 10 times as reliable as hdds (just be aware that when they do fail, they tend to do so catastrophically, and without warning, so backups are even more important then for hdd's ).

With respect of durability, while the number of write cycles is limited, modern SSDs like the 860 EVO are extremely reliable, and even for extremely heavy users - eg server databases - will survive many years.   Installing and running games and Windows is certainly not a problem at all for any current SSD.

Not that its an issue, but you mention a 1TB SSD.  The larger the SSD, the less you need to worry about wear, because in effect data can be rewritten to more places, and wear leveling can be even more effective.